# how do i arrange the months of the year in chronological order using power BI service

Tags: powerbi

I'm working with power bi service, I want to visualize a monthly data but the months of the year aren't arranged in chronological order, how do i fix this

Comment: What order are they in? What type of data is it? date? Text?
Welcome to stackoverflow,  help us help you by asking a question in the right way. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may help to show what you have tried, some example data, or screenshots and expected outcomes

Comment: hi, I have the months of the year spelt out e.g January, February, March and so on, but when I visualize on power bi service, it doesn't appear in the right order, that is, the 3rd month might appear first, the column is in the text format

Answer (score 0):

The dataset you're using in Power BI service must be edited to sort the month names by month number. This is a data modeling issue, and you cannot achieve your goal purely through service reporting tools. You did not specify what type of data source you have. Since Power BI Desktop is the data modeling tool for Power BI Service, I have explained how to do this with Power BI Desktop.

**The best method** is to create a calendar table and relate it to your fact table. [Here is an article](https://radacad.com/creating-calendar-table-in-power-bi-using-dax-functions) on creating one with DAX. In your calendar table, you should have a column containing the ordinal month number (1-12) and the month name. I like one column with the month short name (Jan, Feb, Mar...) and one with the month long name (January, February, March...). For each of the month name columns, select the column in the field well, in the app menu, select Column Tools > Sort by column and choose the month ordinal number column to sort the name column.

If you have a fact table with just month names in it and you want to do something **quick and dirty**, you can create a month ordinal number column on the fact table and sort the existing month name column by that.

```
Month Number = MONTH(DATEVALUE(YourTable[YourMonthNameColumn] & " 1, 2022"))
```

Comment: hi Dani, thanks for your reply, however this process only works for power bi desktop, I can't seem to do this on power bi service